# Automated dictionary entry filling in PowerShell from input command line arguments

Tags: windows, powershell

In PowerShell script I have a dictionary(variable input below) which I want to fill from command line arguments.

```
script to execute: ./win.ps1 -var1 <value> -var2 <value> -var3<value>

param($var1, $var2, $var3)
$input = @{"var1" = ""; "var2" = ""; "var3" = ""}

if ($var1){
       $input["var1"] = $var1}
if ($var2){
       $input["var2"] = $var2}
if ($var3){
       $input["var3"] = $var3}
```

If I have a lot of arguments can I automate the above task of filling the dictionary entry (may be in a loop), provided the key of dictionary and the param variable name, where we are receiving the input parameters are same.

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest you to have it in a csv file and pass the file to the script.

```
Name                           Value
----                           -----
var2                           2
var3                           3
var1                           1
```

And inside your script

```
$HashTable = Import-Csv -Path $CSVPath | ForEach-Object -Process { @{$_.Name=$_.Value} }
```

Comment: I can not understand his question. Would you explain what he means by dictionary

Comment: @RobertCotterman, Dicts ==> key value pairs, PowerShell has similar with hashtables.

Answer (score 1):

you are using `$Input` as a variable. that is an automatic variable, so you likely otta NOT do that. you are likely to get some very odd results.

from `Get-Help about_Automatic_Variables` ...

> $Input
>       Contains an enumerator that enumerates all input that is passed to a function. The $input variable is available only to functions and
>   script blocks (which are unnamed functions).  In the Process block of
>   a function, the $input variable enumerates the object that is
>   currently in the pipeline. When the Process block  completes, there
>   are no objects left in the pipeline, so the $input variable enumerates
>   an empty collection. If the function does not have a Process block,
>   then in the End block, the $input variable enumerates the collection
>   of all input to the function.

hope that helps,
lee

Answer (score 0):

Just use $args variable, and use it for set an hashtable. Remove param($var1, $var2, $var3)
into your script, its not necessary in your case

Comment: But shouldn't it enforce the user to give the parameters in calling script in specific order only?

Comment: why? If user use -Arg1 value1 -Arg2 value2 etc... you can then translate what he want no? :)

Answer (score 0):

You could use $args automatic variable and hashtable to hold parameter name and its value. Like so:

```
function Do-Things{

    $hashtable = @{}
    for ($i = 0; $i -lt $args.Count; $i += 2)
    { 
       $hashtable[$args[$i]] = $args[$i+1] 
    }
    $hashtable
}
$Results = Do-Things -af df -fds 421 -fgsd hfd
$Results
```

Output:

```
Name                           Value                                                                                                                                                               
----                           -----                                                                                                                                                               
-fds                           421                                                                                                                                                                 
-fgsd                          hfd                                                                                                                                                                 
-af                            df
```

You could also access specific keys:

```
$Results['-af']
```

Output:

```
df
```

Also, like **@Lee_Dailey** already mention do not use `$Input` automatic variable to hold data.

Comment: Thanks. It really worked. But I want to do this specific task inside a function. Is there a way to do it, since in the current approach $args lose its scope inside a function.

Comment: @SusmitaMandal, you can create intermediate variables to hold $args data before it gets overwritten. `$MyTempArgs = $args` and create global or script scope hashtables to access it. `$global:hashtable = @{}`